# How to use HttpClient send a form data request?

Tags: angular

Currently, I want to upload a file to our server. I can do it with  `Http` from `@angular/http` lib.

But now, we want to change using `HttpClient` to align with the current project. I searched around, but I couldn't find a solution on how to add a form data to the post request using `HttpClient`?

Here's the code that I used to upload file by http:

```js
let formData: FormData = new FormData();
formData.append('file', file, file.name);
this._http.post(base_api_url + uploadFileApi, formData)
```

Any ideas on what to try next?

Answer (score 28):

**UPDATE: It's important to do not set the 'Content-Type' header, because the navigator will set it automatically based on the FormData you have created; otherwise, it'll not work properly.**

Example of Content-Type auto-generated:

```
content-type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryglPFUvMDIrKwHaRK
```

---

Here is the `Angular` service to do that:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class UploadService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadFile(file: File): Observable<any> {

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);

    const headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'enctype': 'multipart/form-data' });

    return this.http.post(apiUrl, formData, { headers: headers });

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this should be present in the official doc though.

Answer (score 0):

It can be written as simple as this. Where path is the request path and data is your form data.

```
 constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
            this.httpTimeout = 90000;
            this.retryCount = 1;
    }

method(path: string, data: any) {
    this.httpClient.post(path, data).retry(retry).timeout(timeout);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i tried but it didnt work for me.

Comment: What is the error you are getting, please provide logs

Comment: this  is how i use http from @angular/http


let formData: FormData = new FormData();

formData.append('file', file, file.name);


this._http.post(base_api_url + uploadFileApi, formData).subscribe() {...}

Comment: import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http"; for HttpClient